# Trigger inner class while activating container class as 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, this

In my current example you see '.**collapse**' container which is triggered when someone clicks **anywhere** on the div itself. There are many '.**collapse' divs** but each one is triggered individually because of 'this' in the JS. The problem is that I don't want the whole container to be the trigger.

**How can I replace '.collapse' in JS and use h2:after instead but still trigger .collapse as 'this'.**

Let me know if this is confusing so I can edit my question to be more understandable.

**HTML**

```
<div class="collapse">
<h2>sometext
::after
</h2>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

http://codepen.io/mariomez/pen/jyaWax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any `h6` in your code but you can use the `h2` and use `$(this)` and `parent()` to select it's parent. I hope this is what you're looking for:

```js
$('h2').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);
 html {
  height: 100%
}
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none; background:url(https://unsplash.imgix.net/40/OTwgwURiQN6DLk8zIr8E_DSC00953.jpg?q=75&w=1080&h=1080&fit=max&fm=jpg&auto=format&s=408af6f15369c9d232097a79ff997fa7) center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center
}
.wrap {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.collapse {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0px;
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
.collapse * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.collapse.active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 17px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 200;
  color: #444;
  max-height: 3000px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px -10px;
  transition: all 0.2s, max-height 4.8s;
}
.collapse h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative
}
.transparent {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) !important;
  color: #fff !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 10px !important
}
.collapse h2::after {
  content: "+";
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 50%;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 15px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.collapse:hover h2::after {
  opacity: 1
}
.collapse.active h2::after {
  content: "-";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <h1>Collapsible drawers</h1>

  <div class="collapse transparent">
    <h2>I am transparent</h2>
    The brain is like a muscle. When it is in use we feel very good. Understanding is joyous.
    <b>Carl Sagan</b> 
    <p>This one keeps the transparency</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I edited my question. I can't believe that I forgot "parent". Thank you my friend.